# The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a Union query do not match

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have been facing error in MS Access  and error is **"The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a Union query do not match."**

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT sale_head.suppliername AS sale_head_suppliername,
sale_head.invoiceno AS sale_head_invoiceno, sale_head.invoicedate,
sale_details.invoiceno AS sale_details_invoiceno, sale_details.suppliername AS       sale_details_suppliername,
sale_details.product_code, sale_details.qty, sale_details.totalkg, sale_details.Rate,   sale_details.subtotal FROM sale_head 

INNER JOIN sale_details ON sale_head.[invoiceno] = sale_details.[invoiceno] 
UNION ALL select 'Total', sum(sale_details.subtotal) from sale_details

WHERE (((sale_head.suppliername)='Ramkrishna Creation'));
```

Am I missing something ? If yes please do let me know.

Comment: I thought the error was self evident - in a union you need to have an identical number of columns for the unions to line up. Are you trying to return details and a total?

Comment: I would be very worried about this design. Invoicing should not require a union. Totals are easily obtained in a report.

Comment: I want result like this : [Click here for Sample image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5xs69-03ZA_VDdieG96REZoS3c/edit?usp=sharing)
That is why I use Union

Comment: The sample is easy in a report.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

When you union two or more queries together each query should have the same columns of data with same data type for example :

```
SELECT Name,LastName,SUM(Salary) FROM tabel1
UNION
SELECT Text1,Text2,SomeMoney FROM table2
```

is valid (assuming that Name and Text1,LastName and Text2 and Sum of salary and SomeMoney have the same data type but :

```
SELECT Name,LastName,SUM(Salary) FROM tabel1
    UNION
    SELECT Text1,SomeMoney FROM table2
```

(cloumns count mismatch)or

```
SELECT Name,LastName,SUM(Salary) FROM tabel1
    UNION
    SELECT Text1,SomeMoney,Text2 FROM table2
```

(data type mismatch)are not valid union statements.

UPDATE : My answer is according to [SQL Standard Definition of Union Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) which states :

> The UNION operator is used to combine the
>   result-set of two or more SELECT statements.
>
> Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same
>   number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types.
>   Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Comment: I want result like this : [Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5xs69-03ZA_VDdieG96REZoS3c/edit)  That is why I use Union... Any solution pls

Comment: Then you should add some dummy fields to your total line query for example SELECT "Total" as field1,NULL as field2,NULL as field3,.....,SUM(*) as finalfield

Answer (score 1):

In a UNION, both datasets must have the same number of columns but they don't need to be the same datatype

> All queries in a UNION operation must request the same number of fields; however, the fields do not have to be of the same size or data type.

[UNION Operation (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208962(v=office.12).aspx)